# Simplifying fractions with exponents

Tags: real-analysis

I'm revising for an exam, which I have the solutions to. One of the questions asks me to prove that a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, sequence is written as:

$ a_n = \frac{2^{n+2}+1}{2^n},$

and then in the solutions, it has:

$\left | a_n - a_m \right | = \left | \frac{2^{n+2}+1}{2^n} - \frac{2^{m+2}+1}{2^m} \right | = \left | \frac {1}{2^n} - \frac {1}{2^m} \right |$

I am extremely rusty on my math skills, but could someone explain how the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ absolute values are equal?

Comment: $(4+\frac1{2^n})-(4+\frac1{2^m})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$
\frac{2^{n+2}+1}{2^n} = \frac{2^{n+2}}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} = 2^2 + \frac{1}{2^n} = 4 + \frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
Doing the same with the second term (the one involving $m$), we find that
$$
\left| \frac{2^{n+2}+1}{2^n} - \frac{2^{m+2}+1}{2^m} \right|
= \left| 4 + \frac{1}{2^n} - \left( 4 + \frac{1}{2^m} \right) \right|
= \left| \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^m} \right|.
$$

Comment: which is the solution I came to, why does the 4 disappear?

Comment: oh dear, I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The important equality is:
$$\frac{2^{n+2} + 1}{2^n} = \frac{2^{n+2}}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} = 2^2 + \frac{1}{2^n}$$

The same process is performed on both fractions and the $2^2$ drops out. (One fraction contributes a $+4$ while the other fraction contributes a $-4$.)

Comment: Oh dear, I was over analysing. Too long revising, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

hint we have $\frac{2^{n+2}+1}{2^n}=2^{n+2-n}+\frac{1}{2^n}=2^2+\frac{1}{2^n}$ and analogously for the other fraction.